# How much does loading a load cell in other directions than the direction it was designed for effect the readings?

Tags: measurements, sensors

I am looking into using this  [TAL230B miniature type load cell](http://www.htc-sensor.com/products/179.html) to measure forces in x and y direction. The normal sensor loading is displayed in image 1. What is the effect of loading them as in image 2? And what is the effect of putting a rotational force on the end?[image] [image]

Comment: If you want to measure forces in different directions, use a biaxial or triaxial load cell. There are also cells designed to measure torque, if that is what you mean by "rotational force". Applying the load in the wrong direction to a single-axis load cell will produce a meaningless (but probably non-zero) output.